# Different processes, same PID | Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to spawn few processes using the multiprocessing module.
However when I call os.getpid() each process returns the same PID as the main calling process.

Why?
I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
class Listener(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, _ttl):
        super(Listener, self).__init__()
        self.ttl = _ttl
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind(('localhost', 0))

    def get_pid(self):
        return os.getpid()  

    def get_name(self):
        return self.socket.getsockname()

    def run(self):
        self.socket.listen(1)
        time.sleep(self.ttl)

    def listen(self):
        self.start()

class TestEx1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_address_to_pid(self):
        listener1 = Listener(12)
        listener2 = Listener(12)
        listener3 = Listener(12)
        listener1.listen()
        listener2.listen()
        listener3.listen()
        address1 = str(str(listener1.get_name()[0])) + ":" + str(listener1.get_name()[1])
        address2 = str(str(listener2.get_name()[0])) + ":" + str(listener2.get_name()[1])
        address3 = str(str(listener3.get_name()[0])) + ":" + str(listener3.get_name()[1])

        print listener1.get_pid()
        print ex1.address_to_pid(address1)

        print listener2.get_pid()
        print ex1.address_to_pid(address2)

        print listener3.get_pid()
        print ex1.address_to_pid(address3)


        assert(str(ex1.address_to_pid(address1)) == str(listener1.get_pid()))
        assert(str(ex1.address_to_pid(address2)) == str(listener2.get_pid()))
        assert(str(ex1.address_to_pid(address3)) == str(listener3.get_pid()))

        listener2.join()
        listener2.join()
        listener3.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `os.getpid()` is called from the original process that runs the test.

The `Listener` instances are Python objects accessible in the original processes. Because these objects are instances of `multipricessing.Process` they may help the original process to spawn new processes.
In original process of test, however, TestEx1 class is calling  `os.getpid()` via these objects (in the original process). That's why they return same pid.

In order to get pid of the Listener processes, call `listener1.pid` attribute after the process starts. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) explains

> pid
>
> Return the process ID. Before the process is spawned, this will be None.

Comment: How can I fix that problem?

Comment: How about call ing `print 'process id:', os.getpid()` at Listener's  `run ` method?

Comment: Also I found Process instance has `pid` attribute.

Comment: One more thing I dont really understand:
When I use netstat -nptl, each listener listen under the same PID. Why?

Comment: That's interesting. Can you create another question with the latest code, netstat version and Linux version (Ubuntu 14.04) in it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713233/different-processes-showed-as-same-pid-within-netstat

Comment: @Doppelganger I appreciate if you are satisfied with `pid` attribute and you can "accept" my answer for this question.